# Button Style works at runtime but Visual Studio shows errors at design time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I'm using the following Class and DependencyProperty to allow a style to set an image for a Button:

```
public static class ImageButton
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty = 
                  DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Image", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageButton),
                                                                                                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((ImageSource)null));
    public static ImageSource GetImage(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (ImageSource)obj.GetValue(ImageProperty);
    }

    public static void SetImage(DependencyObject obj, ImageSource value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ImageProperty, value);
    }
}
```

I've defined the following Style (in ImageButton.xaml):

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:vcontrols="clr-namespace:Vialis.Led.LedControl5.Controls">

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ImageButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
        <Image  Source="{Binding Path=(vcontrols:ImageButton.Image),
                                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                 AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"
                Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" 
                Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" 
                Stretch="Fill"
                RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
            <Image.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Key="ShrinkStoryboard">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ImageScale" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                                To="0.8"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.15"
                                                AutoReverse="False"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ImageScale" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                                                To="0.8"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.15"
                                                AutoReverse="False"/>
                </Storyboard>
                <Storyboard x:Key="GrowStoryboard">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ImageScale" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                                To="1.0"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.15"
                                                AutoReverse="False"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ImageScale" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"
                                                To="1.0"
                                                Duration="0:0:0.15"
                                                AutoReverse="False"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </Image.Resources>
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="ImageScale" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" CenterX="1" CenterY="1"/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>

            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed" Storyboard="{StaticResource ShrinkStoryboard}"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" Storyboard="{StaticResource GrowStoryboard}"/>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        </Image>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="ImageButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ImageButtonTemplate}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

And finally in order to use it I have something like this:

```
<Button Width="32"
        Height="32"
        Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}"
        vcontrols:ImageButton.Image="/Images/someimage.png"/>
```

When I compile and execute the application everything works just fine.
The button gets an image and uses the animations defined in the Style.

At design time however, Visual Studio cannot seem to visualize it and
the XAML editor shows squiggly lines under the entire button definition.

The error information says:

> Prefix 'vcontrols' does not map to a namespace.

It's refering to the use of vcontrols in the Style.
If you change the name there, the error will change as well,
so it's not related to the name chosen in the Window/UserControl that is using the Button.

What might be causing this and is there a way to fix it so it works at design time as well?

Comment: Have you tried adding the namespace declaration to the XAML document root element? Maybe Visual Studio only looks there for the declarations?

Comment: Try adding the assembly bits to the namespace declaration...  xmlns:vcontrols="clr-namespace:Vialis.Led.LedControl5.Controls;assembly=???"

Comment: Hi, well the assembly is the same as the application (it was an external assembly at first, but I figured moving the controls into the same assembly might solve it... it did not. Explicitly adding ';assembly=Vialis.Led.LedControl5' does not help either, that just makes things worse.

Comment: As I was reading your question the first thing that came tom mind was the same as MaLio's comment. What do you mean by "that just makes things worse"? Is the assembly actually the whole "Vialis.Led.LedControl5?

Comment: Everything is in the same assembly at this point. As for the "worse" part, as soon as I did other errors started showing up. So basically the ImageButton class and the Style are in the same assembly as the WPF windows I'm using it in.

Comment: @TimothyP, I've just test your code pieces with new WPF application project and everything looks fine and works as expected in VS2010 (as far as I could assume) - the image button looks fine in design mode as well. Do you need me to post the complete code from my test project (it will be 95% of your code and 5% from autogenerated project template)?

Comment: @Sevenate it would be great if you could post that. I'll then load it into 2012 see if it still works.

Comment: @TimothyP, I've posted the code, please take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2:**

This issue was only with VS2012 designer (in VS2010 it works fine) and it is already fixed in [**Visual Studio 2012 Update 3**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305) patch.

Comment: Sorry to get back to you so late. Anyway this must be a bug in VS2012 because I get the exact same exceptions.

Comment: @TimothyP, I've checked it with VS2012 Update 2 - the issue is in place. According to [few](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/779344/vs2012-xaml-designer-fails-to-resolve-binding-to-attached-property-in-a-style) [other](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/783339/visual-studio-2012-update-2-xamlparseexception-in-wpf-designer-binding-attached-property) similar complains you are right - this is VS2012 issue, I believe. Good news - it is already fixed in [Update 3 RC2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=39067)! :)

Comment: @TimothyP, I could confirm that this issue with design time is finally fixed in [**Update 3 RC2**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39067) - tested on my machine a few minutes ago.

Comment: BTW, you will need only **VS2012.3 RC.exe** (1.3 MB) web installer.

Comment: Installing now, will let you know :)

Comment: It works like a charm... which StackOverflow had a way of giving out medals for really taking the time to solve an issue. Thnx!

Comment: @TimothyP just in case - today this Update 3 was released, so I've update link to the release version of it. Things changing fast now-days :)